# how to test and export iOS app made with LibGDX

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, libgdx, robovm

much of the title already establishes what I need help with. The problem is that [RoboVM](https://robovm.com) is shutting down and no longer providing any service :( so I cant use it, nor can I find anything similar. Please help, thank you.

I'm using a mac, AndroidStudio, and I already have Xcode installed.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the [oficial libgdx site](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3925)  there's a lot of alternatives like:

```
Mobile OpenJDK 9
J2ObjC
Avian
Xamarin + IKVM
Intel Multi-OS Engine
```

Tomski is writing the multi-os engine backend for a oficial release, if you need any help with it you could probably ask him personally on the #libgdx freenode irc channel.